# Трясет объект когда оно находится между двумя объектами

Tags: c#, unity3d

Для начала шар больше размером и физически не может пролезть через этот проход, но когда шар застревает между двумя объектами, во-первых его начинает трясти туда сюда , во-вторых когда шар выходит на свободное пространство , то самопроизвольно начинает двигаться медленно направо, после того как его потрясло. Как это можно исправить? Я искал ответ в интернете, наверное не смог правильно сформулировать вопрос или что,  но не нашел ответа как это исправить. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 void FixedUpdate()
{

    if (allBlock)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(-0.1f * Time.fixedDeltaTime * speed, 0, 0);

        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(0.1f * Time.fixedDeltaTime * speed, 0, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {

            transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0.1f * Time.fixedDeltaTime * speed, 0);

        }

        if (!Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(0, -0.1f * Time.fixedDeltaTime * speedY, 0);
        }
    }

    if (!allBlock)
    {
        transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0.5f * Time.fixedDeltaTime * speedY, 0);
    }

}
```

**Я сделал так и все работает . Знаю это все не правильно, жду критики и советов.**

```
public float speedVelocity = 2;
public float speedVelocityDown = 1;

bool allBlock = true;
Rigidbody rb;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

}


void FixedUpdate()
{

    if (allBlock)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(-speedVelocity, speedVelocity, 0);
            }
            else if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(-speedVelocity, -speedVelocityDown, 0);
            }


            rb.AddForce(Vector3.left * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(speedVelocity, speedVelocity, 0);
            }
            else if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(speedVelocity, -speedVelocityDown, 0);
            }


            rb.AddForce(Vector3.right * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(-speedVelocity, speedVelocity, 0);
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(speedVelocity, speedVelocity, 0);
            }
            else
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, speedVelocity, 0);
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        }

        if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(speedVelocity, -speedVelocityDown, 0);
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(-speedVelocity, -speedVelocityDown, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, -speedVelocityDown, 0);
            }
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.down * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
    }

    if (!allBlock)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, speedVelocity, 0);
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

}
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "Finish")
    {

        allBlock = false;

    }
}
```

**Физика как у шара в реальном мире , которой можно управлять.**

Comment: возможно ты передвигаешь круг телепортацией, поэтому коллайдеры и не запрещают проход сквозь такое узкое пространство. покажи код перемещения чтобы уточнить. UPD: перемещение коллайдера без "твердого тела" - плохая практика, на это тратится время

Comment: Rigidbody есть на всех объектах.

Comment: Мало иметь твердое тело на объекте. Нужно и перемешать объект с его помощью. Если перемещать не так то коллайдеры будут выталкивать ваш объект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Возможно движение шара реализовано неправильно, как сказал dgzargo. Если оно реализовано через изменение позиции в пространстве -- это неправильно. Должно быть реализовано через какой-нить AddForce() или что подобное.
2. если движение шара реализовано правильно, то скорее всего дело в том, что шар движется слишком быстро. В таком случае нужно изменять настройки ригитбоди на более детальную обработку коллизии коллайдером. Это кажется настраивается в самих настройках обьекта в ригитбоди скрипте. collisionDetectionMode или как-то так.

после твоей обновляхи вопроса видно что что проблема в п.1. Ты занимаешся телепортированием обьекта))

Так же полезно будет почитать: [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа | почему мой персонаж дергается | для чего нужен Time.deltaTime](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4)

Comment: Но на сколько верный новый код который я добавил?

Comment: ну это уже лучше. Но еще лучше -- посмотри в сторону кода по линке в моем ответе. Но если работает и так -- это не критично. Не забывай голосовать за все коментарии которые тебе помогли и ответы. Как и отмечать ответы верными.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо за советы.